# Building C++ files Using Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I need help displaying my build results for c++ in sublime text 3. I can build the program fine. When I press ctrl-b it builds my program and an executable file is created and stored at the location of the c++ script I'm building. But my problem is I want the results of the build to also display in the console screen when I build. Right now it just gives me the time it took to complete the task.

Specifically, I'm testing this with a simple hello world program and I can display the results fine if I use the command prompt terminal. However, I don't want to be using this to display my results, but rather I want everything to be done in sublime text 3. Please, any help will be much appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out! In case other people have this same problem, all you have to do is hold ctrl+shift+b to run the program. Ctrl+b builds it, and ctrl+shift+b runs it.